# Power Query From Web dynamical DAX

Tags: import, powerquery

I am courious about how to make M coding more dynamically when finding data. Currently i am trying to gather day-to-day stock data. I am Currently using this line of M-code to get the data

```
= Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MATAS.CO/history?period1=1372377600&period2=" & "1600214400" & "&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"))
```

The part "1600214400" is supposed to change each day. However, I tried different ways to make this dynamic. For instance, I used Advanced mode when using Get From Web. But that also failed. I also tried to use other queries, tables and output from functions. Does anyone have any idea or thoughts about to make this part dynamic?

I have enclosed a picture on how it looks on advanced.

I Googled this problem and some pictures illustrated the possibility of using parameters when using From Web. But I do not have that feature...

[image]

Comment: Just to note, this is NOT Dax, it is the M language. DAX is in the Power Pivot/Tabular engine. I have edited question to correct this

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small function (see `unixTimestampForStartOfToday` in code below), which gives you a Unix timestamp in seconds for the start of "today" (where "today" is the date (per UTC) on which the code is running.

You can then use it as the value of the `period2` query string parameter -- meaning `period2` should always reflect the current date (per UTC).

```
let
    unixTimestampForStartOfToday = () as number =>
        // Should return the unix timestamp for today's date (as per UTC) 
        // at 00:00 hours.
        let
            todayFloored = DateTime.Date(DateTimeZone.FixedUtcNow()),
            unixTimestampInSeconds = Duration.TotalSeconds(todayFloored - #date(1970, 1, 1))
        in unixTimestampInSeconds,
    Source = Web.Page(
        Web.Contents("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MATAS.CO/history", [
            Query = [
                period1 = "1372377600",
                period2 = Number.ToText(unixTimestampForStartOfToday()),
                interval = "1d",
                filter = "history",
                frequency = "1d"
            ]
        ])
    )
in
    Source
```